# How to handle multiple parameter in case statement in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, select, case, where-clause

I using an ORACLE query. Im stuck in my query which is very similar to the below code / condition.
I have multiple terms and based on terms, conditions with multiple values should pass as below.

Terms:

1. First Quarter
2. Second Quarter
3. First Half

   ```
   MONTHS IN (CASE WHEN terms = 'First Quarter' THEN ('JAN','FEB','MAR') 
                    WHEN terms = 'Second Quarter' THEN ('APR','MAY','JUN')
                    WHEN terms = 'First Half' THEN ('JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','JUN')
                    ELSE ('JUL','AUG','SEP','OCT','NOV','DEC')
                    END )
   ```

When i execute the same above query, error message displays as **ORA-00907 - missing right paranthesis**
and i couldn't find out the reason.

Please provide suggestions in terms of fix and also for **Performance** as i have multiple conditions in original query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use boolean logic to describe your conditions rather than a `case`  expression:

```
   (terms = 'First Quarter'  and months in ('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR'))
or (terms = 'Second Quarter' and months in ('APR', 'MAY', 'JUN'))
or (terms = 'First Half'     and months in ('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN'))
```

This can be shortened a little:

```
   (terms in ('First Quarter',  'First Half') and months in ('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR'))
or (terms in ('Second Quarter', 'First Half') and months in ('APR', 'MAY', 'JUN'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option; sample data from line #1 - 8. Query you might be interested in begins at line #9. Depending on what tool you use, `'&&terms'` might look different than this (e.g. `:terms`). This is SQL*Plus. Also, I used abbreviations instead of your "quarters" and stuff (didn't feel like typing that much).

```
SQL> with months (mon, num) as
  2  (select 'jan', 1 from dual union all
  3   select 'feb', 2 from dual union all
  4   select 'mar', 3 from dual union all
  5   select 'apr', 4 from dual union all
  6   select 'may', 5 from dual union all
  7   select 'jun', 6 from dual
  8  )
  9  select *
 10  from months
 11  where mon in
 12    (select *
 13       from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('jan', 'feb', 'mar'))
 14       where '&&terms' = 'FQ'
 15     union all
 16     select *
 17       from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('apr', 'may', 'jun'))
 18       where '&&terms' = 'SQ'
 19     union all
 20     select *
 21       from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun'))
 22       where '&&terms' = 'FH'
 23    )
 24 order by num;

Enter value for terms: SQ

MON        NUM
--- ----------
apr          4
may          5
jun          6
```

--

```
SQL> undefine terms
SQL> /
Enter value for terms: FH

MON        NUM
--- ----------
jan          1
feb          2
mar          3
apr          4
may          5
jun          6

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```